# Excel range disposition by rows or columns

Tags: vba, excel

There seems to be an undocumented attribute for the Excel `Range` class that determines how the `Item`, `Cells`, and `Count` properties work (as well as other class methods and properties, most likely).

Ordinary `Range`s seem to have "Cell" disposition; i.e. accessing their properties takes a Cell index.

```
Set x = [A1:H50]

?TypeName(x)
Range

?x.Address
$A$1:$H$50

?x.Count
 400 

?x(20).Address
$D$3
```

But you can also obtain a "Column" or "Row"-dispositioned `Range`, which behaves differently.

```
Set x = [A1:H50].Columns

?TypeName(x)
Range

?x.Address
$A$1:$H$50

?x.Count
 8 

?x(20).Address
$T$1:$T$50
```

I'm trying to write a wrapper class for `Range` that will behave better than the built-in type for multi-`Area` ranges. I'd like to have a better understanding of how this range "disposition" works. Is there a built-in property or otherwise simple way to test what "disposition" a `Range` object has? Is the "disposition" an immutable property of the range or is there a way to change it without obtaining a new range using the "Rows", "Columns", or "Cells" properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unaware this behavior even existed. I looked through the Range Object's property listing but I couldn't find anything that addresses this need for your wrapper. Instead I wrote a function that I think tells you the "Disposition", I called it orientation.

```
Function getOrientation(ByVal Rng As Range) As String
    'If only one row, it's a column orientation
    If Rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        getOrientation = "Column"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'If only one column, it's a row orientation
    If Rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        getOrientation = "Row"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'If the cell count matches the expected cell count, it's Both
    If Rng.Count = Rng.Columns.Count * Rng.Rows.Count Then
        getOrientation = "Both"
    ElseIf Rng.Count = Rng.Columns.Count Then
        getOrientation = "Column"
    Else
        getOrientation = "Row"
    End If
End Function

Sub Test()
    'Testing
    Debug.Print getOrientation(Range("A1:B100").Columns)
    Debug.Print getOrientation(Range("A1:B100").Rows)
    Debug.Print getOrientation(Range("A1:B100"))
    Debug.Print getOrientation(Range("A1:A100"))
    Debug.Print getOrientation(Range("A1:C1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: this would fail with multiple-area ranges like `Range("A1:B2, C3:D5")`. You could enhance your code to handle such ranges too but I think that the "real" way @Tmdean is looking for is a new `Class` where to place all wrappers he needs

Comment: Yup agreed, more of an example of how to tell the orientation. Where is the indicator in your class below? E.g. Rng.Count will return the number of rows when the range is Defined like [A1:A100].Rows, not the number of Columns.

Comment: There's no indicator property because I don't need it once you directly and properly loop through Areas property of the Range object. The ColumnsCount property was just an example; a similar RowsCount one can be easily added to properly count the rows number of multi areas ranges

Answer (score 1):

Actually [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837125.aspx) says

> Returns a **Range** object that represents the columns in the specified
>   range

which means it returns a `Collection` of columns, so that `.Count` would return the number of collection elements i.e. the number of columns

but it also adds:

> When applied to a Range object that's a multiple-area selection, this
>   property returns columns from only the first area of the range. For
>   example, if the Range object has two areas — A1:B2 and C3:D4 —
>   Selection.Columns.Count returns 2, not 4.

while immediatly giving the way out:

> To use this property on a range that may contain a multiple-area
>   selection, test Areas.Count to determine whether the range contains
>   more than one area. If it does, loop over each area in the range

Hence the need for some *wrappers* to enhance the default members of `Range` object

This would be the perfect room for `extension methods`, which are unfortunately not possible in VBA

So the next move should be to define a Class

For instance you may add a new Class named after "MyRange" with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng As Range

Public Property Set Range(r As Range)
    Set rng = r
End Property

Public Property Get Range() As Range
    Set Range = rng
End Property


Function ColumnsCount() As Long '<-- your personalized "Columns.Count" function correctly calculates the number of columns of your range
    Dim area As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    For Each area In rng.Areas
        ColumnsCount= ColumnsCount+ area.Columns.Count
    Next area
End Function
```

and you code would exploit that "MyRange" Class as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rng As Range ' "normal" range type
    Dim myRng As MyRange ' your "personalized" range type

    Set rng = Range("A1:B2, C3:D5") '<-- set a "normal range" object

    Set myRng = New MyRange '<--| set your "personalized range" object
    Set myRng.Range = rng '<-- give it the "normal" range as its "rng" property

    MsgBox rng.Columns.Count '<-- this will return 2
    MsgBox myRng.ColumnsCount '<-- this will return 4
End Sub
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, except I did some VBA stuff to make the MyRange class implement a default property, iterator function, and to carry a "disposition" flag so that it behaves just like the built-in Range type except that it supports multi-area ranges and some other features I wanted.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I actually think that the "disposition" isn't a real thing while "Areas" property is the key for properly handling (and extending) range objects built-in properties. Anyhow you may found the "disposition" a useful abstraction for your further coding. You may also want to share your Class code in [Code Rewiew](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for enhancement. Finally, since I seem to have answered your question (that was about better understanding of the "Columns" property working and hence about the "disposition") you may want to mark this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you think it's not a real thing... the return type of Columns and Rows is "Range"; it doesn't return a collection type... it returns a Range that behaves in a slightly different way for a few properties and methods.

Comment: It's not _"it returns a Range that behaves in a slightly different way"_ because an object must behave in the same way. It's that it _"Returns a Range object that represents the columns in the specified range"_ and _"When applied to a Range object that's a multiple-area selection, this property returns columns from only the first area of the range"_ . So this is `.Columns` property that behaves like that, not `Range` object. The bottom line is that the real thing is bother/handle `Areas` property of `Range` object

Comment: It may help considering that a _collection_ is a group of objects of the
same class, like for instance `Worksheets` or `Workbooks`, and a collection is itself an object, like `Worksheets` is an object of type `Sheets` (not `Collection`). So `Selection` object acts as a _collection_ that may consist of `Range` objects (each cell in the `Range` selection is a `Range` object). And this latter example is pretty much what happens with `Columns` property of `Range` object: it returns a _particular_ `Range` selection, i.e a _collection_ on which you can call, for instance, the `Count` method

Comment: "main" is from C programming, where you have a main entry-point to a program. Excel VBA is an event-driven paradigm, so "main" is an unclear function-name.

Comment: @johnywhy, "Main" is a perfectly legal name for a Sub in VBA
 
in this case I'm using "Main" as the name of an exemplifying Sub that uses "MyRange" Class
But you can rename it as per your needs with whatever other VBA legal name for a Sub

Comment: @user3598756 True, `main` is a perfectly legal function name.